# Error when trying to run GRASS 7 via processing toolbox in QGIS 2.18 on Mac

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, osx

I have gone through the following steps:

1. Installed the following packages that came with QGIS 2.18:

   1. `1 GDAL Complete.pkg`
   2. `2 NumPy.pkg`
   3. `3 matplotlib.pkg`
   4. `4 Install QGIS.pkg`
2. Installed GRASS-7.4.1 from [GRASS GIS for Mac](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads) by drag-and-droping it into the `/Applications` folder.

When I now try to run `v.net.nodes` in the processing toolbox, I get the following errors:

[image: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' See log for more details]

[image: It seems that GRASS GIS 7 is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS GIS 7 algorithms.]

The `log` reads the following:

```
2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
self.processAlgorithm(progress)
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Algorithm.py", line 297, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass7(self.commands, progress, self.outputCommands)
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py", line 298, in executeGrass7
command, grassenv = Grass7Utils.prepareGrass7Execution(commands)
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/Grass7Utils.py", line 289, in prepareGrass7Execution
command = Grass7Utils.command + ' ' + os.path.join(Grass7Utils.grassMapsetFolder(), 'PERMANENT')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
1   There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

I am guessing that `Grass7Utils.command` is `Null`, which tells me, that `Grass7Utils.py` does not know where to search for `GRASS 7`.

Do I need to configure QGIS for it to know where to find `GRASS 7`? If yes, how is this done?

Comment: Does this error arise when calling *any* GRASS module or just v.net.nodes (or a few modules)?